# Floating point exception (core dumped) cpp

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Hey guys I was using Sieve of Eratosthenes for Prime Factorization of a given no "n" in cpp but it shows an error :

"Floating point exception (core dumped)"

the code goes like this:-

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void primeFactor(int n)
{
    int arr[100] = {0};
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0)
        {
            for (int k = i * i; k <= n; k = k + i)
            {
                arr[k] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    int primeFactors[n] = {0};
    for (int i = 0; n > 1; i++)
    {
        n = n / arr[n];
        primeFactors[i] = arr[n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << primeFactors[i];
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    primeFactor(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What `n` did you try with? `if (arr[i] == 0)` This is an out of bounds access waiting to happen, and there are a couple more later.

Comment: `for (int k = i * i; k <= n; k = k + i)` ?? For `k == n` you are also out of bounds for `k >= 100`.

Comment: `int primeFactors[n]` is not valid c++, use `std::vector` instead. Your crash is probably a divide by zero error caused by one of `arr[n]` being zero

Comment: `int k = i` rather than `int k = i * i` might fix the crash but I'm not sure your algorithm works even with this fix

Comment: @dxiv i tried with 8 and 21 . and "this is an out of bound access waiting to happen" can u plz explain this line

Comment: @AlanBirtles i generally make arrays like this only for ex- int arr[n]; i think its valid.         If u see arr[n] cant be zero untill and unless i have given a prime no. as n                       see this part of the code                                                                                                    `void primeFactor(int n)
{
    int arr[100] = {0};
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0)
        {
            for (int k = i * i; k <= n; k = k + i)
            {
                arr[k] = i;
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: If you have clarifications to make edit them into the question, posting code in the comments doesn't really work, `n` will always be a prime number for the last iteration of your loop so `arr[n]` can definitely be 0

Comment: @everyoneeverywhere You define `arr[100]` but then use `arr[x]` with `0 <= x <= n`, so for `n >= 100` that will be an out of bounds access and buffer overrun.

Answer (score 0):

In this block of code:

```
if (arr[i] == 0)
{
    for (int k = i * i; k <= n; k = k + i)
    {
        arr[k] = i;
    }
}
```

You never set `arr[i]` so all of the prime numbers in `arr[i]` are set to `0` resulting in a divide by zero exception in your second loop. The initial value of `k` should be `i` not `i * i`.

There are a few other issues in your code:

1. you store the prime factor after changing the value of `n`, you need to swap those two lines
2. in your third loop `n` is now `1` so you only ever print the first factor.
3. in `int primeFactors[n]` `n` is not a compile time constant so this is not valid c++ and only compiles due to a GCC extension, using `std::vector` would be better and also helps to solve problem 2.

Here's a working version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void primeFactor(int n)
{
    int arr[100] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] == 0)
        {
            for (int k = i; k <= n; k = k + i)
            {
                arr[k] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    std::vector<int> primeFactors;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        primeFactors.push_back(arr[n]);
        n = n / arr[n];
    }

    for (int f : primeFactors)
    {
        cout << f << ", ";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    int n = 28;
    primeFactor(n);
    return 0;
}
```